# Web accessibility: does it make sense for focus to go to another element other than the whole page frame or the first focusable element on the page?

Tags: dialog, keyboard, focus, accessibility

My question is about focus management for web accessibility. When we launch a popup/dialog, does focus always need to go to the first focusable element for accessibility reasons or is it acceptable to set focus on an element that we think the user is more likely to want to work with?

For example, if a dialog starts with an input field and a cancel link followed by a dropdown and we think the user would most likely want to work with the dropdown when the dialog loads, is it ok to set focus on the dropdown element? In this case, how would the user know about the previous focusable elements existing on the dialog? But, if the dropdown is where 80% of the users will want to be when the dialog is launched, it doesn't make much sense placing focus on the initial input field...

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research and what public opinion is: http://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=5435 it seems like where the focus goes for a modal dialog/popup would depend on the usecase. For example, it makes sense to set focus on the search input field for www.google.com although there are preceding elements that the user can interact with -- this maximizes usability for screen reader and keyboard only users. But, in general the focus needs to go to the first element the user can interact with -- depends on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would caution against setting focus to anything other than the first form element or headings/content that introduce the form. See [WCAG 2.0 Focus Order](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-focus-order.html):

> If a Web page can be navigated sequentially and the navigation
>   sequences affect meaning or operation, focusable components receive
>   focus in an order that preserves meaning and operability. (Level A)

While the case you present is I think an edge case, I think the focus order rules still apply. If you think that most users will want to interact with the select why not put it first in the form rather than set focus to an element in the middle of the form?

Comment: Thanks for the response. An example of the usecase I am talking about is: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form Say, the form in the dialog begins with a link that says 'Help?' and then a Cancel link or an X link and then the form begins. The common use case is for the user to want to fill in the fields in the form and if the design cannot be changed at this point, would it make sense to put the focus in the first form field? If users use this form multiple times in the day to fill in info (like admin assistants in a hospital), would it be inaccessible to set focus in the 1st form elt?